# How can play back combat logs in real time?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm trying squeeze the last ounce of DPS from my spec and a guildie helpfully provided a video of his rotation on the combat dummy.  However, I'm finding it pretty hard to follow just from watching the animations, buff bar, and quickbars (particularly since the latter are laid out very differently from mine).

Is there any way to show the name of the move as it is executed from the combat log?  I'm aware of live parsers but using and recording them won't always be an option (or useful if I'm interested in a specific log).

Comment: Just curious, but why try to learn from a video rather than from a succinct explanation? I haven't played SW:TOR, but from the other similar games I've played, usually a rotation is fairly easily described in terms of a priority list based on a few conditions (if this buff is up and this skill has cooldown under x, use y, otherwise check this next priority, then this next, etc). This is a much easier way to communicate it than mimicing a rotation (i.e. you learn "why" rather than "what" and then trying to reverse-engineer "why")

Comment: @Peter Yeah, we've done that, it's just down to extremely fine details at this point.  Rather than going into "OK so if X is high and the boss does Y and you're lucky and Z procs, then do A, B, and C" sort of thing we went with the video so I can see what happens as situations evolve.  Plus I'm pretty sure one of the things we're trying is a bug.  I also intend to use this for world boss fights where the mechanics aren't fully known yet and manually going through combat logs is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Parsec (a live parser) is capable of displaying live ability uses. It definitely helps with buffs.

Or, if you're skilled programmer, the combat logs are not too hard to read - they have all the ability names and damage values, you just need to clear away junk data.

> [13:40:20.305] [@Alexeì] [Operations Training Dummy {2857785339412480}:147009782894] [Weaken Mind {812861215473664}] [ApplyEffect {836045448945477}: Damage {836045448945501}] (1411* internal {836045448940876}) <1411>

Timestamp | Entity - Initiator | Target | Ability Name (Weaken Mind in this case), followed by ability code (812861215473664 - this also comes from in-game ability XMLs) | ApplyEffect tells you what happens, i.e. damage, heal, or buff/debuff. After that there is damage value and the type (Internal, Elemental, Kinetic, et cetera) and a final number, 1411, again, the damage that went out.

If you are just after ability names, it should not be too hard to clear junk data.

Comment: I don't want to see things live, I'm interested in analysis after the fact.  I'm also quite familiar with the combat log format.  This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MatthewRead then I am afraid I do nut understand your query. You asked if there was a way to show ability as it is executed, but you do not want it live? Isn't "as it is executed" the same as live?

Comment: As per the title, I want to play logs back after the fact.  Abilities should be shown in real time as the log is played back, i.e. the time between moves should be correct.  Not the same as being live, again as per the question -- "I'm aware of live parsers but [they won't be] useful if I'm interested in a specific log".

Comment: @MatthewRead so you want to log e.g. a fight and want to replay the log like you would watch a video did i get it right here?

Comment: @Nitro.de Yes that's basically the idea.

Comment: @MatthewRead well I would real time parse the logs whenever i need, maybe bound as a keyboard shortcut so you just parse them if needed. While parsing i would take the time it needs for the parser to find the next needed line. Lets say you attack an enemy and it takes 0,5sec for the next attack so the parser would need the same time to find the second attack in the log. Just write the things you need in a xml file and add the time. If you want to replay the whole thing just parse the xml and emulate the fights with the saved time hope you got my main idea here^^

Comment: @Nitro.de Creating my own logs and parser for them is absurd.  If I wanted to put in that much effort, I'd put in less and write a parser for the existing logs.  I know how to do that, but that's not the question.

Comment: @MatthewRead could we discuss this in chat? I guess I misunderstood what you trying to achive